# onkeyup activates many ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

In an entry I use the onkeyup function so that every time I type it, I activate a javascript function, which makes requests to the server using ajax, the problem arises when the user types quickly, so with each key that he / she touches, activates an ajax request which causes me many requests, and also brings me bad results.
I do not know if it is understood, I hope someone can give me an idea of ​​how to change this.
Thank you

Comment: Simple. Don't attach Ajax request to event's like `keyup`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This kind of ajax call is not good idea**.

Anyhow,

- You should do ajax call when user has typed at least **3-4 letters**.
- You can also add some a check to see if user has **typed something and stopped writing** then do the ajax.
- If you still want to do ajax on each character then try to do very light ajax means get very **small data from server**.

**Check if input length is > 3**:

```
var userInput = $('#inputFiled').val();  // get user input  and save into js variable
if(userInput.length > 3){   //if user input is at least 3 characters
  //do ajax here
}
```

**To check if user has stopped writing**

To do so you will have to use underscore.js

```
$('#userInout').keyup(_.debounce(yourAjaxCallFunctionHere , 500)); 
underscorejs.org/#debounce
```

**You can also achieve this using jQuery**

```
var delayInAjaxCall = (function(){
      var timer = 0;
      return function(callback, milliseconds){
      clearTimeout (timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, milliseconds);
   };
})();
```

**Usage Of Above Function**

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
   delayInAjaxCall(function(){
   alert('Hi, func called');
   }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: What type of check can I implement?

Comment: If you have an example, it will be very useful

Comment: This is to check how many letters the user entered. But to know if I stop writing? Do you have any? Sorry for so many doubts

Comment: just check if input field has focus and at least 3 characters.

Comment: If it's okay, thanks for the example, but to check if I stop writing?

Comment: To do so you will have to use underscore.js 
$('#userInout').keyup(_.debounce(yourAjaxCallFunctionHere , 500)); 
https://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: One last question, the code would fall something like that? $ ('# userInout'). keyup (_. debounce (function () {
$ ajax ({})

}, 500));

Comment: Sorry I asked so much, is that I'm not well trained in the field of javascript or jquery

Comment: Yes exactly. It will work. No problem at all man. Help other when you have enough knowledge. You will learn more and fast

Comment: If the truth is that you are right. Would not you mind giving me your contact? Because I see that he is a man of many knowledge. If you want to talk to me with my email tespindola@codigobyte.com.ar

Comment: Not an issue. Please check inbox.

Comment: I replied, it seems that you have not reached anything, now I talk to you again

Comment: One question, do you have any idea how I can collect the input data?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the below JS code and achieve with few lines of codes,

```
let timer = null;

on_key_up(){

  //if input length < 3 return it

  if(timer){
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
  }

  timer = window.setTimeout( ()=>{
   FireMyEvent()
  }, 1000);

}
```